# Jquery - keeping it DRY - dynamically named functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I think the best way for me to keep my code is to call a function with a dynamic name. For example, I might need to call "productTemplate", "userTemplate", "orderTemplate", etc...

Is this possible with javascript/jquery? Also, is it a performance hit or not so much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about storing those functions under an object? You could probably call those function names dynamically by using `eval` or accessing them with `window[type + 'Template']`, but the object implementation seems easier and cleaner.

```
var templates = {};
templates.order = function (order) { /* ... */ }
templates.product = function (product) { /* ... */ }
templates.user = function (user) { /* ... */ }

my_element.innerHTML = templates.user(my_user);
```

(Also, the [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) plugin created by Microsoft might help with what you're particularly trying to do. It's so good that it's gonna be built right into jQuery 1.5, dontchaknow.)

Answer (score 4):

It's possible in basic JavaScript, no jQuery needed, whatever the object is, even `window` you can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation), for example:

```
var methodName = "productTemplate";
obj[methodName](); //exe obj.productTemplate();
```

The same holds true for global functions, just replace `obj` with `window`.  You can do this with your jQuery plugins or core as well though, for example here's how [`.toggle(bool)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle2) works, actually using [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) internally:

```
$("selector")[bool ? "show" : "hide"]()
```